# SQLite: no such table: while compiling

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I've got a long running task that I run onResume on my activity. The task involves querying a database then decrypting some data, then manually sorting it then updating the sort order in the database using a transaction.

This works fine when I run it from the Activities main UI thread, but when I execute the same task from within an AsyncTask I always get these errors:

- I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(5166): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Household, db=/mnt/sdcard/myDatabase.db
- no such table: while compiling: no such table: Household: , while compiling: `SELECT DISTINCT street FROM Household WHERE street IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(street)))>0`

I know that the database exists and that SQL statement is fine because it runs fine outside the AsyncTask. Is there something about access my database from within an AsyncTask that causes problems?

I'm getting errors on the "SELECT DISTINCT" raw query below.

```
private boolean update_street_sort_order() {
    boolean returnValue = false;
    DBUtilities objDbUtil = null;
    Cursor cCases = null;
    final String SORT_ATTRIBUTE = "street_sort_order";
    final int STREET_INDEX = 0;
    final int ENCRYPTED_STREET = 0;
    final int DECRYPTED_STREET = 1;
    try {
        objDbUtil = DBUtilities.getInstance(this);
        if (objDbUtil != null) { // Get list of cases
            ArrayList<String[]> alStreet = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase = objDbUtil.getDatabase();
            if (sqlitedatabase != null && sqlitedatabase.isOpen()) {
                cCases = sqlitedatabase.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT street "
                        + "FROM Household " + "WHERE street IS NOT NULL "
                        + "AND LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(street)))>0", null);
                String _password = this.context.getPassword();
                if (cCases != null && cCases.moveToFirst()) {
                    do { // Create list of en/decrypted streets
                        alStreet.add(new String[] {
                                cCases.getString(STREET_INDEX),
                                Crypto.decrypt(_password,
                                        cCases.getString(STREET_INDEX)) });
                    } while (cCases.moveToNext());
                }
                if (cCases != null) {
                    cCases.close();
                    cCases = null;
                }
                int alStreet_length = alStreet.size();
                if (alStreet_length > 0) {
                    Collections.sort(alStreet, new Comparator<String[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(String[] lhs, String[] rhs) {
                            return lhs[DECRYPTED_STREET]
                                    .compareToIgnoreCase(rhs[DECRYPTED_STREET]);
                        }
                    }); // sort decrypted street using custom comparator
                    StringBuilder sql_transaction = new StringBuilder(
                            "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" + "UPDATE Household SET "
                                    + SORT_ATTRIBUTE + "=NULL;");
                    for (int i = 0; i < alStreet_length; i++) {
                        sql_transaction.append(String.format(
                                "UPDATE Household " + "SET "
                                        + SORT_ATTRIBUTE + "=%1$d "
                                        + "WHERE street=\"%2$s\";", i,
                                alStreet.get(i)[ENCRYPTED_STREET]));
                    }
                    sql_transaction.append("COMMIT;");
                    // execute transaction
                    sqlitedatabase.execSQL(sql_transaction.toString());
                }
                returnValue = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Utilities.getFullMethodName(e), e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (objDbUtil != null) { // release resources
            objDbUtil.close();
            objDbUtil = null;
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
```

Comment: Where is the code that created the DB table "Household" ? share it

Comment: The database table Household is pre-packaged with the app and is not created by the SQLiteOpenHelper. As I stated above, the database table Household exists and is operated on prior to running the AsyncTask, so I know that it exists and is reachable.   Is this a context problem?

Comment: in `objDbUtil.getDatabase()` - are you referencing that per-packeged DB? with exact DB file location and name

Comment: yes:    `public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {  
  if (this.database == null || !this.database.isOpen()) {  
   this.database = this.getWritableDatabase();
  }  
  return this.database;  
 }`

Comment: @Sean, Where `this.database` gets set in the getInstance() using `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, factory, flags)`

Comment: I never was able to find a root cause for this issue so I abandoned use of the AsyncTask in my onResume code.